# Unknown variable within object

Tags: tcl

Why is the variable not visible to the proc if called from another proc?

```
package require itcl
itcl::class foo {
   protected variable _name
   proc constructor {} {
      set _name Juan
   }
   proc name {} {
      return $_name
   }
   proc name2 {} {
      return [name]
   }
}
set bar [foo ::#auto]
puts [$bar name]
puts [$bar name2]
```

This outputs:

```
Juan
can't read "_name": no such variable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not fully conversant with incrTcl, but I think you don't use `proc` at all. The constructor should be

```
constructor {} {
    set _name Juan
}
```

and use the `method` keyword

```
method name {} {
    return $_name
}
method name2 {} {
    return [name]
}
```

Then

```
% set bar [foo ::#auto]
::foo0
% puts [$bar name]
Juan
% puts [$bar name2]
Juan
```